# SQL - max of a column corresponding to two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

A table contains four columns "server", "directory", "usage" and "datetime". All servers has got 10 dirs in common. I need to get the data for a server and it's any dir the usage for the latest datetime in a day.
Say for example if there is a server A with directory B there will be Usage at multiple time for few days. I need the data to be reported by the query for all servers it's all corresponding directory's usage for the latest entry on each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to see the last usage for every server and directory. Given a table named "usagestats" with the given columns that would be:

```sql
SELECT a.server, a.directory, a.`usage`, a.datetime
    FROM usagestats as a INNER JOIN (
        SELECT server, directory, max(datetime) datetime
            FROM usagestats
            GROUP BY server, directory
        ) AS b ON (
            a.server = b.server
            and a.directory = b.directory
            and a.datetime = b.datetime
        )
    ORDER BY a.server, a.directory, a.datetime
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Daniel you hit it right on the head. I being a novice was using the following query and I was not getting the latest usage.: SELECT server_id, usage_mb, (usage_mb*100)/(available_size_mb+usage_mb) percentage FROM tbl_disk_utilization WHERE datetime in (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM tbl_disk_utilization GROUP BY DATE(datetime), server_id, storage_directory_id) GROUP BY server_id, storage_directory_id ORDER BY server_id, storage_directory_id;

Comment: Just for the completion I had to modify your suggestion a little bit, following was my final query:SELECT T1.server_id, T1.storage_directory_id, T1.usage_mb, T1.datetime FROM tbl_disk_utilization AS T1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT server_id, storage_directory_id, MAX(datetime) datetime FROM tbl_disk_utilization GROUP BY server_id, storage_directory_id, DATE(datetime)) AS T2 ON ( T1.server_id = T2.server_id AND T1.storage_directory_id = T2.storage_directory_id AND T1.datetime = T2.datetime ) ORDER BY T1.datetime, T1.server_id, T1.storage_directory_id; Thanks again Daniel, your help is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that i understand correctly your question.

MySQL has IF() function, that returns one of statements according to condition in first parameter.

If you want to select data from column where number is bigger and there are only 2 columns - use IF statement like this:

```
SELECT 
if(columnA > columnB, columnA , columnB) as grtColumn,
if(columnA > columnB,'columnA is bigger', 'columnB is bigger') as whichColumnWasGrt

from yourtable;
```

Help: [mysql reference - if() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) (there are IF statement and IF() function - diffrent thigs!

Comment: Thanks much for your interest Kamil towards my query. I have gone through your suggestion and the control functions page which I was not aware of.